# java script hover effects reacting together

Tags: javascript, html, hover, mousehover, onhover

I'm still a newbie to coding, and I'm learning as I go. I'm currently trying to build up my first web page, and I've hit a snag.

I got some hover-over effects from W3school, and applied them to two image button links. I made two different "Raw HTML" entries into two different columns. When i load the webpage, the buttons always react together. If I hover over one image, the other image's effect is triggered. I had something similar where I had two auto-play galleries, and when I put them both on the page, they conflicted with one another.

What coding logic do I need to be able to separate elements?

Here is the site in question: 
http://centralia2050.dreamhosters.com/gallery-links/

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The code responsible for your hovering effect is the following:

```css
.container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This essentially says: When hovering over an element with the class `.container`, set the `opacity` property of all child elements that have class `.middle` to 1.

Since there is a `.container` Element which contains both of your `.middle` Elements, both of them have their opacity set to 1 when hovering over that `.container`.

The solution to your problem would be to use the `:hover` pseudo-class on a selector that specifies elements which only contain one `.middle` element.

What you are probably looking for is to fade in the `.middle` elements only when hovering over your `#gallery1` and `#gallery2` elements, so you could change the code like so:

```css
#gallery1:hover .middle, #gallery2:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Even better, create a class `.gallery-container` and apply it to the `#gallery1` and `#gallery2` elements. Then use the following snippet:

```css
.gallery-container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm beginning to understand. The desired effect I want is for each element to be independent so when I hover over one, it doesn't activate the effect on the other, and vice versa.
This is effectively my problem when I'm trying to create any group of buttons or images on a page. I think what I need to spend time learning about are these "div classes" and how they work. 
Thank you!